# Play different MP3 files one by one in VB.Net 2019

Tags: vb.net, mp3, windows-media-player

I am creating a small forms application in VB.Net 2019 that will scan my harddrive for MP3 files and then play them in random order.
At this moment I scan my disk and load everything in two listboxes (one for the path, one for the filename because I also want to export in CSV). Somewhere in the future this data will go in a database with extra information so I can choose the genre of music I want to randomly play at that moment.

When I click my cmdRandom commandbutton, the first file starts to play but when I want to continue with the next random file, the file is searched and loaded into media player but doesn't start playing (I have to click "play" manually).
Here's my code:

```
Private Sub cmdRandom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdRandom.Click
    intaantal = ListBox2.Items.Count
    Randomize()
    PlayMedia()
End Sub

Private Sub PlayMedia()
    intNumber = CInt(Int((intAantal * Rnd()) + 1))
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = intNumber
    ListBox2.SelectedIndex = intNumber
    FileName = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\" + ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
    lblSongText.Text = FileName
    '       mPlayer.URL = ""
    '       mPlayer.Refresh()
    '       mPlayer.close()
    '       mPlayer.settings.autoStart = True
    '       mPlayer.settings.setMode("loop", True)
    '       mPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play()
    mPlayer.URL = FileName
End Sub
Private Sub mPlayer_PlayStateChange(sender As Object, e As _WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent) Handles mPlayer.PlayStateChange
    If mPlayer.playState = mPlayer.playState.wmppsMediaEnded Then
        PlayMedia()
    End If
End Sub
```

All items in PlayMedia() that are commented out have already been tested but don't work. I thought that adding ***mPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play()*** in the mPlayer_playStateChange () function in an else clause of the current if would work but that gives me a compilation error (seems to not be allowed in this event).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you written a `Randomize` sub or are you using the built-in `Randomize`? If you're using the built-n `Randomize`, then there is your mistake - the buil-in one changes the seed number in random number generation - It has nothing to do with randomizing lists :-) - I'll be posting an answer below based on this assumption - later this evening when I've written it all :)

Comment: @DavidWilson, Think the OP might actually be right with the randomize.  First line in the PlayMedia method he's getting his random line id.  That aside, my feeling is even if the Random thing wasn't working it would still play something.  Perhaps the better thing is to debug the mPlayer_PlayStateChanged event to ensure that is working as Expected

Comment: Are you saying that you have conformed that, if you set a breakpoint on that `PlayMedia` method, it does get hit when you expect it to and all the code in it executes and does exactly what you expect?

Comment: I've placed breakpoints at different locations in the code to see what was going on and see the "playStateChanged" event fired each time it should be fired. Only when the song has finished playing it, as expected, calls "PlayMedia" again. I then see that the new file is selected from my list, loaded into the control and a label is updated (as you can see in the code). However the file is not playing, I have to click the play button to get it started.
So I'm convinced I have to do something extra to reset the mediaplayer control to make it start with the new song.

Answer (score 0):

Found the sollution on the web after another search: (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/31082234-7161-4446-a96e-32c0314dfe0f/actions-when-a-media-player-control-finished-playing?forum=vbgeneral). It all has to do with the time between the end of the first song and the loading of the next.
I added a timer and things are fixed now, I set the timer interval to 100.

```
 Private Sub mPlayer_PlayStateChange(sender As Object, e As _WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent) Handles mPlayer.PlayStateChange
    If mPlayer.playState = mPlayer.playState.wmppsMediaEnded Then
        mPlayer.Ctlcontrols.stop()
        Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()
    PlayMedia()
End Sub
```